# NSIS WriteINIStr Unicode

Tags: unicode, ascii, nsis

I am trying to build a NSIS installer for an application I have written.

The installer takes a number of user details and writes these into an INI file. The issue I am currently having is that the INI file created is ASCII. This means that if a user enters anything Unicode or from an unsupported language I get `????` within the ini file.

Using NSIS how do I write Unicode INI files?

Update 1:
Okay, so upon noticing there is a new version of NSIS (v3.0a) which has more options for Unicode i thought I would install this to see if it works.

The previous application code is fully compatible and the exe was built, but, the issue still remains that the WriteINIStr does not write unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest stable release 2.46, NSIS does not support unicode and you should have to build the .ini file yourself via `FileOpen` / `FileWrite` / `FileClose` and converting text through the system plugin.

There is a long-awaited unicode branch that is brewing since 2009 and I did not noticed that a [v 3.0a0](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download) was just released and is available on the download site. (Until that you needed to check out the code and build the binaries yourself).

You should give it a try with it.

**Edit**: I have made a little script to demonstrate how to write an UTF-16le text file "by hand" with NSIS 2.46, you could try if your string with "exotic" characters from the text box is correctly writen into the test file

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Name "unicode246"
OutFile unicode246.exe
ShowInstDetails show

Section

    StrCpy $1 "héhé © reçu" ;some "exotic" french chars
    StrLen $2 $1

    System::Call "*(&w${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN} r1)i.s"    ;allocate a buffer and write in wide char
    Pop $0  ;get the buffer address

    FileOpen $9 $EXEDIR\test.txt w ;Opens a file for writing

    ;write UTF-16LE BOM
    FileWriteByte $9 "255"
    FileWriteByte $9 "254"

    ;compute the buffer byte size
    IntOp $2 $2 * 2
    IntOp $2 $2 - 1

    ;loop on the bytes
    ${forEach} $1 0 $2 + 1
        IntOp $3 $0 + $1    ;compute the address of the nth byte

        System::Call "*$3(&i1 .r4)" ;read the byte in $4
        DetailPrint "address $0 + $1 = $3 = $4"
        FileWriteByte $9 $4
    ${next}
    FileClose $9
    System::Free $0 ;free buffer
SectionEnd
```

Comment: I had jus tried the unicode branch but found that WriteINIStr still only does ASCII (how annoying) I will try your suggestion shortly.

Comment: did you explicitly [enable unicode](https://github.com/NSIS-Handbook/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/Unicode.md)?

if the 3.0 alpha doesn't work for you, there's also the 2.46 [unicode fork](http://www.scratchpaper.com/) of nsis.

Comment: I made a prototype to create a utf16-le file from nsis 2.46, hope it will help

Comment: Thanks @seki, I will let you know how I get along.

Comment: @idleberg I looked into the unicode fork, but the WriteINIStr was still only in ascii though.

Comment: @MattWritesCode: btw, did you tried if you write the .ini file with unicode characters yourself (e.g. with Scintilla / UltraEdit / whatever) if it is working as expected by the program that reads the .ini file?

Answer (score 2):

`WriteINIStr` calls WritePrivateProfileString and while the Unicode version (WritePrivateProfileStringW) also writes as ansi by default, it will write as UTF16LE [if the .ini file has a BOM](http://www.siao2.com/2006/09/15/754992.aspx).

So you can use the basic NSIS File* functions to see if there is a BOM, if not you can add it before using the ini commands...